# How easy would reunification be after Second American Civil War?

Tags: warfare, government, politics, alternate-worlds, geopolitics

So in a story series I've been writing, it is set in an alternate 21st century where the United States of America reorganized itself into a theocratic imperial military dictatorship (think Gilead in "The Handmaid's Tale"), but it isn't long until most states along the West Coast secede to form a secular republic that opposes the theocratic America.

The Theocracy and West Coast war with each other for 20+ years, occasionally reaching a stalemate until one side attacks the other and resumes the fighting until the next stalemate, turning the Great Plains States into a war-torn battlefield/Iron Curtain-like border. The West Coast is more favored by the United Nations and European Union, viewing them as the successor to the USA while viewing the Theocratic America as a rogue country with nukes.

Eventually though, thanks to resistance cells and some outside help, the West Coast States manage to win the war and defeat the Theocracy...but now what?

I want to know the specifics of how difficult the reunification of two Americas would be in real life. What are the challenges and easy parts? Are there any IRL stories (besides Germany, which was reunited peacefully) of countries being reunited after war? I'll be sure to edit this if you need more specifics.

Comment: this seems a bit too close to reality man.

Comment: @meaninglessname I think the idea that the entire US with the exception of the West Coast would reorganize into a theocratic dictatorship is kinda out there. The North is arguably less religious than even the West Coast, and I don't see how a more religious South could bring them into line considering the South's relative poverty in relation to the North

Comment: Perhaps the unification of countries like China or Vietnam might be useful considering that they were divided for what I assume is a similar amount of time to what you're talking about

Comment: I am pretty certain that the U.S. of A. itself is an illuminating example of reunification after the War of Secession. As for European countries created with iron and blood in the 19th century, look at Germany and Italy. You may also want to look up the history of Yugoslavia, which was created after WW1, dissolved into warring rival states during WW2, was reunited after WW2 and broke up into pieces at the end of the 20th century. In Asia, we have the example of China which was divided by a bloody civil war.

Comment: I think this question seems opinion-based or story-based: This question seems to be about politics, which you can resolve any way you need to for the plot. Especially imaginary politics.

Comment: As much as I'd like to see this question answered - it's too story-based and opinion-based. You'd need to provide so many details that you'd answer your question in the process. A little insight, though: It could be argued the United States today has still not reunified after the original Civil War. Barbara Fields once said, "...If some citizens live in houses and others live on the street, the Civil War is still going on. It’s still to be fought, and regrettably, it can still be lost." The quality of your story must reflect the complexity of civil war. It's not simple.

Comment: And to really drive my point home: the movie *Edge of Tomorrow* reflects the lack of reunification with the lines,  “Oh, you're American,” ... “No, sir, I'm from Kentucky!” Most of us laughed when we heard that, but the fact still stings - and there's plenty of people shaving their heads, waving Confederate flags, arming themselves and blowing up buildings, right up until today. In fact, consider last week's riots. The hate and distrust draws a pretty straight line back to the Civil War. In many ways, reunification takes centuries and may never fully take place.

Comment: I agree with JBH. Germany was officially reunited 30 years ago, but there are still vast differences in political orientation, culture (even language to a degree) and income / wealth between the former parts. Education differs because quite some teachers who are still teaching now were trained during the division. More subtle differences only become visible at certain times, like the amount of healthcare and childcare available in an area, where people tend to go on vacation or the vaccination status of people. It will take **several generations** for those differences to dissappear.